# How would I solve this equation for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x(x-2)+a(x-2a)=a-1$$

Steps I took:

$$x^{ 2 }-2x+ax-2ax=a-1$$

$$-2a^{ 2 }+ax-a=-x^{ 2 }+2x-1$$

At this point I don't see any way to manipulate this equation to solve for x. A hint would be more appreciated than the actual answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the $-2ax$ has to be $-2a^2$ :
$$\begin{align}x(x-2)+a(x-2a)=a-1&\Rightarrow x^2-2x+ax\color{red}{-2a^2}=a-1\\&\Rightarrow x^2+(a-2)x-2a^2-a+1=0\\&\Rightarrow x^2+(a-2)x-(2a-1)(a+1)=0\\&\Rightarrow (x+2a-1)(x-a-1)=0\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you go from step 3 to 4?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: We have $x^2+(A-B)x-AB=(x+A)(x-B)$ where $A=2a-1,B=a+1$.

Answer (score 4):

Back up a step to

$$x^2-2x+ax-2ax=a-1\;.$$

First correct that to

$$x^2-2x+ax-2a^2=a-1\;.$$

Then collect terms in like powers of $x$ and bring everything over to the lefthand side, getting

$$x^2+(a-2)x-2a^2-a+1=0\;.$$

Now just apply the quadratic formula: the coefficient of $x^2$ is $1$, the coefficient of $x$ is $a-2$, and the constant term is $-2a^2-a+1$.

Comment: As @mathlove has pointed out in another answer, the $-2ax$ term should be $-2a^2$.

Comment: @Théophile: Thanks for ping.